# Updating CentOS 8.3 to Stream got Killed in the middle of process

Tags: linux, centos, centos-8

I am in the process of upgrading my DB server from CentOS 8.3 to CentOS 8 Stream.
I'm using the regular commands:

```
dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
dnf distro-sync
```

And during this last command, all packages got downloaded correctly, and then when upgrading or installing it went wrong only about 1/4th of the way. These are the logs when it went wrong:

> Upgrading        : selinux-policy-3.14.3-97.el8.noarch    235/828
>
> Running scriptlet: selinux-policy-3.14.3-97.el8.noarch       235/828
>
> /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.W8FUgY: line 1: 1442591 Killed    semodule -nB
>
> Running scriptlet: selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-97.el8.noarch      236/828
>
> Upgrading        :  selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-97.el8.noarch          236/828
>
> Running scriptlet: selinux-policy-targeted-3.14.3-97.el8.noarch       236/828
> Killed

If I try to run dnf `distro-sync` again I receive the message:

> Error:  Problem: The operation would result in removing the following
> protected packages: systemd, systemd-udev

Other stuff I tried that keeps returning the exact same error as above:

```
dnf distro-sync --skip-broken
dnf distro-sync --skip-broken --nobest
dnf --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos --best --allowerasing
dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
dnf distro-sync
```

The command `cat /etc/centos-release` does show me  **CentOS Stream release 8**, however seeing that the upgrade process got killed already at 236/828, It feels that there may still be stuff not ok ?

Comment: I have the same error on a VM with 500Mb RAM, increasing RAM to 1Gb seems to help.

Comment: More RAM - more expensive, so, adding a swap file helps with the "yum update" problem as well